# How to find public groups assigned to list view in apex?

Tags: apex, list-view, public-group

We want to get a list of public groups assigned to list view in Apex code. We didn't found object/API which can provide this details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using Metadata API ?
Follow these links for more info on how to achieve this using Metadaapi:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_listview.htm

This link, in particular, retrieves the groups which have access:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_sharedto.htm